# Spark server logs are trimmed

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to fetch the spark server logs for the particular event. But it is getting trimmed in the middle itself

For Eg: If i have a process instance Id of 862939, i will be having a list of events such as for Start, Exception and Completed.

> Start/Completed Event Logs: { timestamp:dd/mm/yyy,"log
> level"="INFO","source"="/path", "exception"="","message"=""}
>
> Exception logs:{ timestamp:dd/mm/yyy,"log
> level"="ERROR","source"="/path",
> "exception"="java.lang.NumberFormatException: for input string: {

As you could see the exception logs get truncated in the middle itself without even having all the other fields followed by exception. Could anyone help me to get the full logs for the exception.

Comment: Can you show how are you logging the exception?

Comment: I have been logging using the log4j.properties which has the following parameters

Comment: @koiralo log4j.logger.com.baml.ctrltech=DEBUG, sampleappender log4j.appender.sampleappender=org.apache.log4j.rollingfileAppender log4j.appender.sampleappender.maxBackupIndex=10 log4j.appender.sampleappender.maxFileSize=50MB log4j.appender.sampleappender.File={{ app-dir }}/spark.log log4j.appender.sampleappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout log4j.appender.sampleappender.layout.ConverstionPattern={"timestamp":"dd/mm/yy","loglevel":"%p","source"="%l","exceptiontype":"%throwable{1}","message":"%throwable{0}}"